# Unable to drag using image within anchor link in Chrome or IE

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, google-chrome, draggable

This is going to be fairly hard to explain, so I've put together a JsFiddle to help demonstrate. http://jsfiddle.net/j5TKr/

I've tried to include everything that I require without complicating it too much. The overall aim is to have a list of `li`'s which can be selected (single click, ctrl-click, shift-click) or double-clicked to be opened. The selected `li`'s can be dragged around (so that they can be moved into other folders). The JsFiddle doesn't have the `li`'s being grouped together correctly, but I'm not worried about that as it is actually working correctly.

The **problem that I have** is that in Google Chrome and IE (and possibly other browsers - **not** Firefox) you can't drag the `li`'s around using the image within the anchor. Or more specifically, in Chrome it doesn't drag until you release the mouse button. If I remove the image (the "This one works" text link) it works. If you drag using the image information below the actual anchor, it works as well.

I gather it's a problem to do with me wanting to be able to click and select `li`'s without actually opening the links.

Sorry if this is all a bit confusing. I'll answer any questions that come up.

Comment: +1 for JsFiddle. It looks interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s an HTML workaround effective in IE and Google Chrome.

Instead of marking your draggable elements up like so:

```
<div class="icon">
  <a title="assets" href="[link]">
    <img src="[image]" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Mark them up like so:

```
<div
  class="icon"
  style="width: 90px; height: 90px; background: url('[image]')">
</div>
```

(You could, of course, separate the added CSS from the HTML.)

Comment: Good idea and I think it'll work for my needs too. I'll try it on Monday.

Comment: Made it work like this. I'd still like to know what was stopping it though. Seems to have something to do with IE treating dragging the anchor as a special thing (drag it to your address bar/bookmark bar etc).

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when trying to drag anchors. I ended up using an `<input type="button" />` so that it could still get keyboard focus.